# Java Applet to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, bufferedimage

I created a JFrame that loads an external applet for a game like so:

```
//Setup everything for the Stub.. Below adds the stub to the applet and creates it.
DownloadFile(new URL(World + "/" + Archive), "./gamepack.jar");
CAppletStub Stub = new CAppletStub(new URL(World), new URL(World), this.Parameters);
applet = (Applet) new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL(World.toString() + "/" + Archive)}).loadClass("Rs2Applet").newInstance();

applet.setStub(Stub);
applet.init();
applet.start();
applet.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Width, Height));
Frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
```

I'm trying to screenshot this applet or get it to draw its surface in a BufferedImage. I tried subclassing "Applet" and casting my URLClassLoader to that class but it can't cast which makes sense.

How can I capture everything the applet is rendering into an Image?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for any Component, not only Applets:

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Component component) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), 
        component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    component.paint(g);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: You should dispose the `Graphics` object once you're done with drawing: `g.dispose()`

Comment: This creates a Black Image when used with the Applet :S

Comment: @gcvt: No, the Javadoc of Graphics.dispose() says "Graphics objects which are provided as arguments to the paint and update methods of components are automatically released by the system when those methods return".

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I've just tested it with an Applet and a JApplet runned by appletviewer: it works, check again or post your code.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for normal Swing Applications. Don't know if loading an applet into a JFrame causes any problems.